# concatenate items on list using range loop and append

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to concatenate the strings in a given `list` using a loop and the append function. (*I know I can use the `join` function, but I am trying it for practice.*)

The error I am getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "trial1.py", line 4, in 
>   q.append(lista[i])
>   AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Here is my code:

```
lista = {'a','p','o','o','r','v','e'}
q = lista
for i in range(7):
  q.append(lista[i])
```

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` is a `set`, not a `list`.  A list uses square brackets `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: even if i correct the code, error persist  lista = ['a','p','o','o','r','v','e']
q = lista[0]
for i in range(7):  q.append(lista[i])
    print(q)

Comment: `lista[0]` is a string.  Strings do not have an `append` method.  What exactly are you trying to do?  What output do you expect?

Comment: i am trying concatenate the string items of a list using loop, so basically i am trying to do this: in starting, i stored first string item of list in variable q, then with the help of loop , i am adding other items of list using append function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do when you have a list of strings that you want to concatenate into a single string:

```
print(''.'join(['a','p','o','o','r','v','e']))
```

To see a similar solution using an explicit loop, we can use the concatenation operator `+` to join strings.

```
lista = ['a','p','o','o','r','v','e']
res = ''
for s in lista:
    res = res + s
print(res)
```

Note that `+` doesn't change the strings it acts upon because strings are immutable.

Comment: so you have stored null value in res variable, by  using (' ') this thing, because i have doubt that, while using this code, the output should be     " apoorve",but actual output coming is "apoorve"

Comment: `''` is an empty string. If you want the first character to be a space, you can start with `res = ' '` if you want.